# What type of switch

Tags: switches, identification

I have some pictures and I hope to find somebody that can help me to identify this type of switch.

[image]

Comment: Looks like a *Rotary Switch*, probably *BCD Encoded* (binary coded decimal: 0123456789 to 4 switches with common.) A distributor like digikey.com, mouser.com, newark, farnel, element14 etc. can help you select exactly which type you need.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a decimal (zero...nine) thumbwheel switch:[image]